# Delete Data from all tables in Sqlserver Database except some tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have A SQLSERVER Database, I want to Delete all tables  except some tables 
i use use this script

```
  EXEC sp_MSforeachtable 'IF OBJECT_ID(''?'') NOT IN (
    ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T1]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T2]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T3]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T4]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T5]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T6]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T7]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T8]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T9]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T10]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T11]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T12]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T13]''),0) 
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T14]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T15]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T16]''),0) 
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T17]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T18]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T19]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T20]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T21]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T22]''),0) 
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T23]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T24]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T25]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T26]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T27]''),0) 
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T28]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T29]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T30]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T31]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T32]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T33]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T34]''),0)
    ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T35]''),0)
    )
   DELETE FROM ?'
```

the sqlserver return this error message `"Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 22
Incorrect syntax near 'ISN'."`

I think the problem may be about the number of tables which is excepted

Comment: Did you try printing out the SQL Statement to check if the syntax is correct?you could be missing a quote or something?

Comment: I printed the SQL Statement, there is not any missing quote

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to do it another way:

```
DECLARE @command nvarchar(max); 

--Remove spaces in front of ,ISNULL 
SELECT @command = N'IF OBJECT_ID(''?'') NOT IN (
 ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T1]''),0)
,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T2]''),0)
,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T3]''),0)
,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T4]''),0)
,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T5]''),0)
...
,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[TN]''),0)
)
DELETE FROM ?'; 

EXEC sp_MSforeachtable @command;
```

NOTE: This SP works only with `nvarchar(2000)` in first command ([source](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/undocumented-sp_msforeachtable-procedure-in-sql-server/)).

> It is the first command to be executed by this Stored Procedure and the data type is nvarchar(2000).

Comment: My pleasure! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
EXEC sp_MSforeachtable N'IF OBJECT_ID(''?'') NOT IN (ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T1]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T2]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T3]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T4]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T5]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T6]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T7]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T8]''),0)
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T9]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T10]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T11]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T12]''),0)
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T13]''),0) ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T14]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T15]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T16]''),0) 
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T17]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T18]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T19]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T20]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T21]''),0)
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T22]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T23]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T24]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T25]''),0)
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T26]''),0),ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T27]''),0) 
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T28]''),0)
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T29]''),0)
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T30]''),0)
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T31]''),0)
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T32]''),0)
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T33]''),0)
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T34]''),0)
                                                ,ISNULL(OBJECT_ID(''[dbo].[T35]''),0)
                                               )
                    DELETE FROM ?'
```

The issue is that `sp_msforeachtable` has first parameter of length 2000 to which your query is passed. Since your query is of length more than that, full text of it is not passed to proc. That's why the error. Shorten the length of query by removing some line breaks. Try my query its working